# Replace or not?

Tags: probability

Two urns contain red and black balls, all alike except for color. Urn A has 2 reds and 1 black, and Urn B has 101 reds and 100 blacks. An urn is chosen randomly, and you win a prize if you correctly name the urn on the basis of the evidence of two balls drawn from it. After the first ball is drawn and its color reported, you can decide whether or not the ball shall be replaced before the second drawing. How do you order the second drawing, and how do you decide on the urn?

Suppose the first ball comes out to be red. We would need to replace the ball because the probability of the next ball being red or black is identical in the two urns.

However, in the second scenario, I wonder if we draw a black ball in the first draw.

```
First Ball   Urn A     Urn B

   R         1R 1B    100R 100B

   B         2R 0B    101R 99B
```

Now, if the first ball is Black, we can calculate the conditional probabilities P(Urn A|2nd Ball is R) & P(Urn A|2nd Ball is B) similarly for Urn B. For convenience, I will denote it by P(Urn A|B) or P(Urn B|R).

Case 1: Without replacement

```
P(Urn A|B) = 0

P(Urn B|B) = 1

P(Urn A|R) = 2/3    (Taking 101/200 ~ 1/2)

P(Urn B|R) = 1/3    (Taking 101/200 ~ 1/2)
```

Case 2: With Replacement

```
P(Urn A|B) = 2/5

P(Urn B|B) = 3/5

P(Urn A|R) = 4/7    (Taking 101/200 ~ 1/2)

P(Urn B|R) = 3/7    (Taking 101/200 ~ 1/2)
```

There seems to be no real advantage in confidence in our probability outcomes in both cases. How do we determine whether to replace the ball or not?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you are allowed to base your replace/no-replace strategy on the color of the 1st ball.

I am going to consider the following four cases separately:

- Case 1: First ball is red and you decide to replace.
- Case 2: First ball is red and you decide not to replace.
- Case 3: First ball is black and you decide to replace.
- Case 4: First ball is black and you decide not to replace.

In each case, I will compute the probability of your guessing the urn correctly.

Then, I will summarize the results by comparing the final computations in Case 1 vs Case 2, and Case 3 vs Case 4.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1: 1st ball red and you replace}}$

The probabilities that it came from Urn A, Urn B are

$$\frac{2/3}{2/3 + 101/201}, ~\frac{101/201}{2/3 + 101/201},  $$

respectively.

You now have to consider the following four possible events:

- The second ball is red, and it came from urn A. 
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{2/3}{2/3 + 101/201} \times \frac{2}{3} \approx 0.38014.$
- The second ball is red, and it came from urn B. 
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{101/201}{2/3 + 101/201} \times \frac{101}{201} \approx 0.21596.$
- The second ball is black, and it came from urn A.
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{2/3}{2/3 + 101/201} \times \frac{1}{3} \approx 0.19007.$
- The second ball is black, and it came from urn B.
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{101/201}{2/3 + 101/201} \times \frac{100}{201} \approx 0.21382.$

So, the probability of the 2nd ball being red is 
$\approx 0.38014 + 0.21596 = 0.5961,$ 
and the probability of the 2nd ball being black is 
$\approx 1 - 0.5961 = 0.4039.$

When the second ball is red, and you (naturally) guess urn A, the probability of your being correct will be 
$\displaystyle \approx \frac{0.38014}{0.5961}.$

When the second ball is black, and you guess urn B, the probability of your being correct will be 
$\displaystyle \approx \frac{0.21382}{0.4039}.$

Therefore, in Case 1, the probability of your guessing correctly will be approximately

$$\left[0.5961 \times \frac{0.38014}{0.5961}\right] + \left[0.4039 \times \frac{0.21382}{0.4039}\right] = 0.38014 +  0.21382 = 0.59396.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2: 1st ball red and you do not replace}}$

The probabilities that it came from Urn A, Urn B are

$$\frac{2/3}{2/3 + 101/201}, ~\frac{101/201}{2/3 + 101/201},  $$

respectively.

**Note**
When the first ball is red, and you do not replace, the probability that the second ball will be red will be $~(1/2),~$ regardless of which urn you are selecting from.

You now have to consider the following four possible events:

- The second ball is red, and it came from urn A. 
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{2/3}{2/3 + 101/201} \times \frac{1}{2} \approx 0.28511.$
- The second ball is red, and it came from urn B. 
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{101/201}{2/3 + 101/201} \times \frac{1}{2} \approx 0.21489.$
- The second ball is black, and it came from urn A.
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{2/3}{2/3 + 101/201} \times \frac{1}{2} \approx 0.28511.$
- The second ball is black, and it came from urn B.
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{101/201}{2/3 + 101/201} \times \frac{1}{2} \approx 0.21382.$

So, the probability of the 2nd ball being red is 
$0.5,$ 
and the probability of the 2nd ball being black is 
$1 - 0.5 = 0.5.$

In either event, the second ball being red or black, you will guess urn A, and the probability of your being correct will be 
$\displaystyle \approx \frac{0.28511}{0.28511 + 0.21382} = 0.57144.$

Therefore, in Case 2, the probability of your guessing correctly will be approximately

$$0.57144$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 3: 1st ball black and you replace}}$

The probabilities that it came from Urn A, Urn B are

$$\frac{1/3}{1/3 + 100/201}, ~\frac{100/201}{1/3 + 101/201},  $$

respectively.

You now have to consider the following four possible events:

- The second ball is red, and it came from urn A. 
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{1/3}{1/3 + 100/201} \times \frac{2}{3} \approx 0.26747.$
- The second ball is red, and it came from urn B. 
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{100/201}{1/3 + 100/201} \times \frac{101}{201} \approx 0.30089.$
- The second ball is black, and it came from urn A.
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{1/3}{1/3 + 100/201} \times \frac{1}{3} \approx 0.13373.$
- The second ball is black, and it came from urn B.
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{100/201}{1/3 + 100/201} \times \frac{100}{201} \approx 0.29791.$

So, the probability of the 2nd ball being red is 
$\approx 0.26747 + 0.30089 = 0.56836,$ 
and the probability of the 2nd ball being black is 
$\approx 1 - 0.56836 = 0.43164.$

When the second ball is red, and you (naturally) guess urn B, the probability of your being correct will be 
$\displaystyle \approx \frac{0.30089}{0.56836}.$

When the second ball is black, and you guess urn B, the probability of your being correct will be 
$\displaystyle \approx \frac{0.29791}{0.43164}.$

Therefore, in Case 3, the probability of your guessing correctly will be approximately

$$\left[0.56836 \times \frac{0.30089}{0.56836}\right] + \left[0.43164 \times \frac{0.29791}{0.43164}\right] = 0.30089 +  0.29791 = 0.5988.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 4: 1st ball black and you do not replace}}$

The probabilities that it came from Urn A, Urn B are

$$\frac{1/3}{1/3 + 100/201}, ~\frac{100/201}{1/3 + 100/201},  $$

respectively.

You now have to consider the following four possible events:

- The second ball is red, and it came from urn A. 
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{1/3}{1/3 + 100/201} \times 1 \approx 0.40120.$
- The second ball is red, and it came from urn B. 
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{100/201}{1/3 + 100/201} \times \frac{101}{200} \approx 0.30240.$
- The second ball is black, and it came from urn A.
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{1/3}{1/3 + 100/201} \times 0 = 0.$
- The second ball is black, and it came from urn B.
  The probability of this occurring is: 
  $\displaystyle \frac{100/201}{1/3 + 100/201} \times \frac{99}{200} \approx 0.29641.$

So, the probability of the 2nd ball being red is approximately 
$0.40120 + 0.30240 = 0.7036,$ 
and the probability of the 2nd ball being black is approximately 
$1 - 0.7036 = 0.2964.$ 
Note the minor rounding error anomaly here.

If the second ball is red, you will guess urn A, and the probability of your being correct will be 
$\displaystyle \approx \frac{0.40120}{0.7036} = 0.57144.$

If the second ball is black, you will guess urn B, and the probability of your being correct will be 
$\displaystyle 1 = \frac{0.2964}{0.2964}.$

Therefore, in Case 4, the probability of your guessing correctly will be approximately

$$\left[0.7036 \times \frac{0.40120}{0.7036}\right] + \left[0.2964 \times \frac{0.2964}{0.2964}\right] = 0.40120 +  0.2964 = 0.6976.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Results}}$

Comparing Case 1 vs Case 2, when the first ball is red, you should replace.

Comparing Case 3 vs Case 4, when the first ball is black, you should not replace.

---

**Addendum**

In retrospect, my work (above) could have been made moderately more elegant.  In any specific case, when deciding on the probability of guessing the urn correctly, you could simply select the two mutually exclusive events (out of 4 mutually exclusive events) that represent correct guesses.

This means that you could avoid (as unnecessary) computing the probability that the 2nd ball will be red vs black.